# How to make new files inherit permissions of parent directory in macOS?

Tags: bash, mac, permissions

I have a directory `python-work` for my python(3) work. I create a new file `test.py`. This file will simply `print('hello world')`.

Trying to run the new file:

```
{mac name}:python-work user$ ./test.py 
-bash: ./test.py: Permission denied
```

A fix is to individually adjust permissions with `chmod +x ./test.py`.

```
{mac name}:python-work user$ ./test.py 
hello world
```

How can I ensure that any new files created within this folder inherit the executable permission from its parent directory, rather than having to individually adjust permissions for each new file?

I would like to acknowledge [this similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31438/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-a-mac-to-make-new-files-inherit-parent-directory-permissio), which did not solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is: you can't.

New files are created with your umask, and not by inheriting permissions from an upper level.

There is a conceptual problem with inheriting permissions from the directory as well. Being executable for a directory means something different than being executable for a file.  If you want to `cd` to a directory, that directory must be executable for you. In your inheritance proposition, it would automatically mean that all the files that you create would be executable if you are able to `cd` to that directory.